# Is it possible to extend typed reactive form definitions to support a 'generic' FormArray?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Using angular typed reactive forms, is it possible to define a FormArray and form definitions such that the array can accept an interface which is then extended by different child interfaces?

Here's an abstracted example:

```
// Define the form
export interface FormArrayDefinition {
    listOfForms: FormArray<FormGroup<CommonFormDefinition>>;
}
```

I want to be able to define a number of extensions of the `CommonFormDefinition` that still fit into this form array:

```
export interface CommonFormDefinition {
    commonField: FormControl<string>;
    commonField2: FormControl<string>;
}

export interface ChildFormAlpha extends CommonFormDefinition {
    alphaField: FormControl<string>;
}

export interface ChildFormBeta extends CommonFormDefinition {
    betaField: FormControl<string>;
}
```

With the goal of being able to accomplish something along the lines of:

```
// In one location in the app
const form = new FormGroup<FormArrayDefinition>(listOfForms: new FormArray<FormGroup<CommonFormDefinition>>([
    new FormGroup<ChildFormAlpha>(/*init controls here*/),
    new FormGroup<ChildFormAlpha>(/*init controls here*/)
]});

// In another location in the app
const form = new FormGroup<FormArrayDefinition>(listOfForms: new FormArray<FormGroup<CommonFormDefinition>>([
    new FormGroup<ChildFormBeta>(/*init controls here*/),
    new FormGroup<ChildFormBeta>(/*init controls here*/)
]});
```

Currently, if I try to define `FormGroup`s of the different child forms and add them to the form array, I get an error

```
Type 'FormGroup<ChildFormAlpha>' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<CommonFormDefinition>'.
  Property 'alphaField' is missing in type 'CommonFormDefinition' but required in type 'ChildFormAlpha'.
```

Why is it not possible to use an instance of a form definition that extends a parent where the parent is expected? Or is there just some syntax I'm missing that is keeping typescript from recognizing the two are related due to the `FormGroup<>`?